Gradio & Blender Python API Conflict?
(Python 3.11)
I was trying to read a Blender file in Gradio, but something weird happened that I can't understand. Here is a simplified version of the problem I met today:
When I try to run this code in gradio, I got error:
import gradio as gr
import bpy

blend_filepath = "/root/shiki/testp.blend"



## bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=blend_filepath)

def read():
    bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=blend_filepath)
    fps = str(bpy.context.scene.render.fps)
    res = str(bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x) + "*" + str(bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y)
    info = "FrameRate: " + fps + "\n" + "Resolution: " + res
    return info



with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    read_blend_file = gr.Button("Read Your Blender File")
    file_info_box = gr.Textbox(label="File Info")
    
    read_blend_file.click(fn=read, outputs=file_info_box)


demo.launch() 


error image
What made me confused is that, if I simply move bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=blend_filepath) out of function that triggered by Gradio button, the problem disappears. Does it means there's a conflict between Gradio and bpy?
import gradio as gr
import bpy

blend_filepath = "/root/shiki/testp.blend"



bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=blend_filepath)

def read():
    ## bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=blend_filepath)
    fps = str(bpy.context.scene.render.fps)
    res = str(bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x) + "*" + str(bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y)
    info = "FrameRate: " + fps + "\n" + "Resolution: " + res
    return info



with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    read_blend_file = gr.Button("Read Your Blender File")
    file_info_box = gr.Textbox(label="File Info")
    
    read_blend_file.click(fn=read, outputs=file_info_box)


demo.launch() 


error disappear
About crash logs:
In Linux (bpy as python3.11 module):
root@mypc:~/shiki# python test.py 
                        * Running on local URL:  http://127.0.0.1:7860
                        To create a public link, set `share=True` in `launch()`.
                        Read blend: "/root/shiki/testp.blend"
                        Segmentation fault (core dumped)

No crash file generated in this case.
In Windows (run test.py in blender):
* Running on local URL:  http://127.0.0.1:7860
To create a public link, set `share=True` in `launch()`.
Read blend: "C:\Users\Shiki\Desktop\TmpRender\tst.blend"

Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address: 0x00007FF75E9C9270
Module: blender.exe
Thread: 0004e28c
Writing: C:\Users\Shiki\AppData\Local\Temp\script.crash.txt

script.crash.txt

Hi, could you include the full error log or traceback? This additional detail will make it easier to identify the issue and provide a more accurate solution. Thanks!

Thanks for reminding me that, I added the crash log just now (but crash log only generated in Windows, as in Linux it just crashed without any info, I don't know the reason.)
